# I don't know why var = int(input()) is error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't know why `int(input())` makes an error

just I do click execute button but it shows me error

I cannot any input string or int

my code is:

```
import sys
input = sys.stdin.readline

def process_queue(queue_list, f_idx, r_idx, command):
   cmd = command[0]
   if cmd == "push":
        queue_list[r_idx] = command[1]
        r_idx += 1
   elif cmd == "pop":
        if f_idx == r_idx:
            print(-1)
        else:
            print(queue_list[f_idx])
            f_idx += 1
   elif cmd == "size":
        print(r_idx-f_idx)
   elif cmd == "empty":
        print(int(r_idx == f_idx))
   elif cmd == "front":
        if f_idx == r_idx:
            print(-1)
        else:
            print(queue_list[f_idx])
   elif cmd == "back":
        if f_idx == r_idx:
            print(-1)
        else:
            print(queue_list[r_idx-1])

    return [f_idx, r_idx]

n = int(input())
queue_list = [0 for _ in range(n)]
f_idx = 0
r_idx = 0

for _ in range(n):
    command = input().split()
    f_idx, r_idx = process_queue(queue_list, f_idx, r_idx, command)
```

Comment: On the second line you set input to a variable. So you overwrite the function of 'input'. Meaning it doesn't exist when you go to call it with input()

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim while not clear why it's used, but `readline` should work pretty much the same... OP says he doesn't even get to enter the input. It would be helpful to see the full error...

Comment: When I copy-pasted and ran your code I got an `IndentationError` on the line `return [f_idx, r_idx]`. I think that error is pretty clear and it would help if you actually posted it...

Comment: @Tomerikoo I don't know if that's a copy paste error on his part, but the return is one space more than is should be.

Comment: @Tomerikoo also, after fixing that one space. If you comment out ```input=sys.stdin.readline``` the script works. But if you leave that in there, it doesn't accept the input.

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim It worked completely fine for me with `sys.stdin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input()
The input takes input from the user but does not read escape character.
It has a prompt that represents the default value before the user input.

sys.stdin.readline()
The readline() also takes input from the user but also reads the escape character.

You are essentially trying to use input() but you named input = sys.stdin.readline()  so that is what's giving you the issue.

Comment: No it's not... as OP said the error is before even being prompted for the input... It seems like an indentation error (assuming the code was copied correctly and is not a typo)

Comment: Thank you very much. I think your comment is similar above comment, right?

Comment: Have a nice day

Comment: To Tomerikoo, I complete this code with some answer. When I write this question, I mistake the carry my code. also Thank you too !

Comment: by the way my English is very low level.... if you don't know what i'm say, comment again, please

Answer (score 0):

This is what's causing the issue:

```
import sys
input = sys.stdin.readline
```

You're basically changing the label input so that it refers to sys.stdin.readline. Read [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-input-and-sys-stdin-readline/).

It would be helpful to see the error message though.

Comment: *You're basically changing the label input so that it refers to sys.stdin.readline* - why would that be a problem?

Comment: oh, Thank you! I know what is the problem. Have a nice day!